# Merge pdf files by timestamp on the file

Tags: batch-file, pdf, merge, pdftk

I have a scheduled task which generates pdf files with the employee_id as the name of the pdf. Daily they get generated and these files are to be merged to a single file based on the creation time.

i have checked for .txt files the same is achieved by using

```
for /F "tokens=*" %%i in ('dir /b /OD *.txt') do type "%%i" >> combine.txt
```

but i am not able to get this functionality for pdf files.
any way or script to do this is much helpful. thanks in advance.

Also i have used pdftk

```
pdftk *pdf cat output.pdf
```

but this generates a pdf with random order not by the creation time.

Comment: i am using windows machine

Answer (score 1):

As long as the number and length of the pdf's doesn't exceed the command line length this should work:

```
@Echo off&SetLocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
Set "EmpPdf="
for /F "tokens=*" %%i in (
  'dir /b /OD *.pdf ^|find /v "combine.pdf'
) do Set "EmpPDF=!EmpPDF! %%i"
pdftk %EmpPDF% cat output combine.pdf
```

Answer (score -1):

Hi there this is a New free online Tool available to merge your PDF Files. This free Online [PDF Combiner](https://www.mergepdf.io/) is one of the most recommended Online tool. You just have to upload your PDF Files and PRess the Merge Buttom that's it. After a Few seconds you can download the Final Combined PDF Files.

Comment: This answer unfortunately does not address the problem. Especially since the task needs to be done daily for who knows how many PDFs, a manual approach is likely not viable.